# Why does pure-ftpwho require root permissions?

Tags: ftp

Why does *pure-ftpwho* require root permissions to run, if you run it without it you get,

> *You must be root to run this. Sorry.*

However, `/usr/bin/who` can run fine without root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [pure-FTPd FAQ](http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/FAQ)

> **How do I give access to the 'pure-ftpwho' command to non-root users?**
>
> The 'pure-ftpwho' command is restricted to root by default, because users
> probably shouldn't be given the ability to spy what other users are doing on
> the same host. However, it's safe to put the setuid bit on that command, in
> order to have it work as any user:

```
sudo chmod 4711 /usr/sbin/pure-ftpwho
```